# Make real ubuntu installation on usb stick

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I made a live usb with ubuntu on it. I can test ubuntu with it but if I want to install it onto the SAME usb stick it is not possible. How can I make a REAL installation of ubuntu onto an usb stick without requiring another usb stick? Is it possible to install ubuntu on the same usb stick you are running the live version on? If not can I somehow run it in a virtual machine with access to the usb stick and install it from there (I tried Linux live usb creator, but it didnt work). Or can I dual boot and then install on the usb stick and delete the linux partition afterwards? If there are other/better options please let me know.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can't install to the same drive you're running a live session from and it should be obvious why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing to the currently booted device is much like digging a hole from underneath your feet. If it allowed you to do that, you would erase the files which are doing the work of erasing and installing. Granted some of the files which are running at the time would be in memory for a moment, not enough of the live environment would survive long enough to complete the install.

You will need to use either a second disk, a method of mounting the live environment / installer or some other method, but whatever the method, it *generally* cannot be from the same disk or stick you are currently running from.

*(I know you technically could rig it up and do it, but it would be way more effort than would be worth as compared even to the price of a second USB stick)*

Comment: But I should be able to install it on the usb stick if I am using dual boot with the hard drive right?

Comment: @Ilovescience No, unless you somehow manage to install Grub and boot the ISO with it, from the hard drive. Definitely not for newbies, even I couldn't do it. You can boot a live DVD the same way and then install to the USB stick but honestly, is it worth the time and effort? It isn't. Just use another USB stick, any USB stick

Comment: @MichaelBay ok thank you for your answer and time.